# Python tuples to tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I get stuck in my school missions about a couple of days! The question asks to copy a tuple into a new tuple which has the different ID with the original tuple! This is my current code but still can't get how to copy with different Ids!

```
def copy_tree(tree):
mylist=[]
for items in tree:
    mylist.append(items)
mytuple=tuple(mylist)
return mytuple
original = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Comment: You code should work fine. Do you know what that "ID" refers to? Also, tuples are immutable, so creating a copy usually does not make much sense anyway.

Comment: Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in Python are immutable, so creating a copy is usually not needed. That's probably the reason, why other than e.g. `list`, `tuple` will *not* automatically create a new tuple if the given parameter already is a tuple:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> list(l) is l  # new list ...
False
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> tuple(t) is t # but same tuple
True
```

You can, however, convert the tuple to a `list` first, and then create a new `tuple` from that list.

```
>>> tuple(list(t)) == t # equal ...
True
>>> tuple(list(t)) is t # ... but not the same
False
>>> id(tuple(list(t))), id(t) # different id
(139852830618896, 139852830618752)
```

Which is basically what you are currently doing, although in a few more lines, so your code should actually work just fine.

---

Note, however, that this will create a *shallow* copy of the tuple, i.e. the objects within the tuple (other tuples, list, whatever) are *not* copied. If you need to copy those, too, use `copy.deepcopy` as in the other answer. However, this, too, is so "smart" that it will not create a copy if the (nested) tuple only contains immutable values:

```
>>> k = (1, (2, "3"))      # all immutable
>>> copy.deepcopy(k) is k
True
>>> k = (1, (2, "3", []))  # contains mutable list
>>> copy.deepcopy(k) is k
False
```

Comment: About your last paragraph: I tried `k = (1, (2, "3"))` and then `deepcopy(k) is k` was `True`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann To be honest, I did not try it, but you are right. Seems like `deepcopy`, too, only copies if there is some mutable object in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
#There is no need to copy immutables. For Academic Purpose:
from copy import deepcopy
#initialising first tuple k
k=(1,2) 
id(k) # checking memory id of k
j=deepcopy(k) #deepcopying k to j
id(j) # checking memory id of j
```

Comment: It will show you that k and j though have same content(k has been copied to j), they are not actually referring to same memory location but are assigned with different memory locations. id(variable) will give you memory ID.

Comment: Maybe the behaviour is different for different version of Python, but it seems like `deepcopy` will _not_ in fact create a copy of the tuple (and all it's contents) is immutable.

Comment: @AvinashKumar No it doesn't show me that. I tried that (in Python 3 and in Python 2) and the ids of `k` and `j` **were the same**. So your "answer" doesn't make any sense to me. Did you really try this yourself and you got different ids? What Python version did you use, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you are looking for but :

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
t2 = t1

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

in this, t2 is a literal copy/clone of t1.

as mentioned before, tuples are not mutable. if you want to add tuple to another you can just use "," as a separator.

You could just add numbers: "t2=t1,1,2,3,4" which would make it tuple copied within another tuple.

or

You could insert numbers from another tuple to another by slicing it like t2=t1[2],1,2,3